# Chart formatting macro getting an "object required" error

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure where this error comes from, but it is thrown even if I comment out everything after the data assignment.

I am new to VBA and have tried many variations of this code and spent hours on it in the past few days, but haven't been able to avoid this problem.

```
Sub fullPageLine()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object

'Data range for the chart
 Set rng = Selection

'Create a chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select

'Give chart some data
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

cht.Activate

'Reposition Title
    With ActiveChart.ChartTitle
      .Left = 24.632
      .Top = 6

    End With

        'Format x axis
            ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
            With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
                .NameFarEast = "Arial"
                .Name = "Arial"
            End With
            Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7

        'Format y axis
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("cht").Activate
            ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
            With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
                .NameFarEast = "Arial"
                .Name = "Arial"
            End With
            Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7

        'Format title
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("cht").Activate
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
                With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                    .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
                    .NameFarEast = "Arial"
                    .Name = "Arial"
                End With
                Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 8.4
                Selection.Left = 23.632
                Selection.Top = 6

        'Format legend
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("cht").Activate
            ActiveChart.Legend.Select
            With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
                .NameFarEast = "Arial"
                .Name = "Arial"
            End With
            Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7

        'Change chart series fill color
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("cht").Activate
                With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
                    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                    .Transparency = 0
                End With
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("cht").Activate
                With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Format.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                    .Transparency = 0
                End With
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("cht").Activate
                With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Format.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
                    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
                    .Transparency = 0
                End With
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("cht").Activate
                With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Format.Line
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
                    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.349999994
                    .Transparency = 0
                End With                 

End Sub
```

I am looking to produce a chart with my specified color and formatting preferences, but this macro as is only produces the default formatted excel chart from the data I select.

Comment: 1) What line throws the error? 2) See [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: It doesn't give me a specific line, which further confused me. I had avoided select, but had been toggling between a few different options to see if anything would work. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: `cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng` is the line producting an error for me. You can actually skip this line as it's written since it already adds the chart from your selection.

Comment: First, I'm surprised this line doesn't throw an error: `Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select` (remove the `.Select` from that). Then try just `cht.SetSourceData ...`.  Also, read through [how to avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Still got the same error after trying both of those. As I said I'm very new to this. Thanks for the help, I will read through both those threads.

Comment: Relying on `ActiveChart` might also be giving you issues.

Comment: I'm hashing through 'getting it to work' but it's not going to be pretty. I'm about halfway

Answer (score 0):

I didn't take the time to really clean this up or anything but I got it working as far as the `collection(5)`. There's a lot to improve here, but that's something I'll let other people tweak and edit to help you learn. right now function, then form.

```
Sub fullPageLine()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object

'Data range for the chart
Set rng = Selection
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
'Create a chart
Set cht = Selection

'Give chart some data
'cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng


'Reposition Title
    With cht
      .Left = 24.632
      .Top = 6

    End With

    'Format x axis
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        With Selection
            .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
        End With

    'Format title
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 8.4
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Left = 23.632
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Top = 6

    'Format legend
        ActiveChart.Legend.Select
        With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
            .NameFarEast = "Arial"
            .Name = "Arial"
        End With
        Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7

    'Change chart series fill color
            With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
            With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
            With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
            With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.349999994
                .Transparency = 0
            End With


End Sub
```